# PHP - Using static attributes and methods

Tags: php, oop, static

If I have a class called Sales, which has only static attributes and
methods:
 - What kind of constructor should I write for this class?
 - How can I make calls to the methods and attributes of this class inside of its own scope?

Comment: I think [this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) shall explain a  lot

Comment: You don't instantiate a pure static class and thus you don't need a constructor. In other words; take some time to learn the difference between objects and classes. A class might be Dog, ``$buster`` might be an instance of this class. A constructor is there to initialise your new object. References to the own instance in an object can be made using ``$this->foo()`` and ``$this->bar``, in static methods you can reference other static elements using ``self::foo()`` and ``self::$bar``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `self::method();` operator to call it's own methods and attributes..

**Constructor**

```
private function __construct()
{
   // Your class variables initialization stuff here
}
```

Comment: What about the constructor?

Ty!

Comment: I don't think you can use `$this` for a static class member. Only `self::` or the name of the class

Answer (score 0):

You can use `self::method();` to call a static method from within the same class.

[More information on static keyword usage](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php)